# Remove locations from list in Reminders app

Tags: ios, reminders

I am trying to remove the locations listed in my Reminders app on my iPhone 5c (iOS 8.2). I have several that I no longer use/need but cannot work out how to delete them? I have the 'home' one and that's the one I use the most.

I have removed locations within the Maps App thinking this may help, but to no avail. Can anyone suggest another method?

Comment: Whilst the device model and iOS version are useful information, the title to your question should be as descriptive as possible regarding what the *problem* is that you are facing. I've edited the title to explain what I believe the actual problem is, but feel free to edit further.

Comment: Wondering the same, I don't know from where this list came from, it's not the same than Maps favorites, it's not related to IOS frequent location neither...

Comment: By the way, how I understand the question is: In Reminders, when you set a location based alerts, you get some address already listed. How are they managed ?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

1. On your iPhone, open the Reminders app.
2. Select the "Home" reminder list.
3. Tap "Edit".
4. At the bottom of the list, tap "Delete List".